# I need some advice for my Cassandra model (time-series)

Tags: model, cassandra, time-series, cql3

I'm a working on an API with nodejs and Cassandra (helenus module), and  I have a cassandra model like the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
  hour TIMESTAMP,
  type int,
  id timeuuid,
  created_at TIMESTAMP,
  invoice int,
  data text,
  PRIMARY KEY((hour, type), created_at) 
 )WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);
```

Now, I have a resource to search for all the types of event for a specific invoice number, so when I do a query like the below one, it returns the rows that match my conditions.

```
select * 
from events  
WHERE hour = '2014-01-20 21:00:00' 
AND type IN (0,1,2)
AND invoice = 123456789 
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 15;
```

But I run in troubles when I want to get all the rows from the beginning of the times related to that specific invoice number because my 'hour' field is restricting me a lot.

And Cassandra has a restriction that you can just use EQ and IN operators in the condition statement for the partition key (hour, type).

What would be the best model for my needs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't filter on arbitrary columns in Cassandra.  You need to know your queries in advance, and design your schema to answer those queries.  Presuming your stated query is the only one you need to run, you can modify your primary key as follows:

`PRIMARY KEY((hour, type), invoice, created_at)`

This will add invoice into the column name to form a composite name, and will allow you to run your query.